# In Python, without using the /proc filesystem, how do I tell if a given PID is running?

Tags: python, linux, unix, operating-system, pid

Say I have a PID, like 555. I want to see if that pid is running or has completed. I can check /proc/ but I don't have access to that in my production environment. What's the best way to do this, short of something hackish like opening a pipe to "ps"?

Comment: Doesn't the Linux `ps` command itself use /proc?

Comment: No. In fact, a lot of environments don't use the /proc file system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`os.kill()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill) function with a signal number of 0. If the process *pid* exists, then the call will be successful, else it will raise an `OSError` exception:

```
try:
    os.kill(pid, 0)
    print("process exists")
except OSError:
    print("process does not exist")
```

The documentation for `kill(2)` on my system says:

> The **kill**() function sends the signal given by *sig* to *pid*, a process or a group of processes.  *Sig* may be one of the signals specified in sigaction(2) or it may be 0, in which case error checking is performed but no signal is actually sent.  This can be used to check the validity of *pid*.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I glossed over kill because of its name. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.kill()` as mentioned by Greg, but realize that the kill system call tests not whether the process exists, but whether you can send a kill to the process.  One failure mode is if the process doesn't exist, but another is that you do not have permission to kill it.  To differentiate, you have to check the exception:

```
try:
   os.kill(pid, 0)
   print 'Process exists and we can kill it'
except OSError, e:
   if e.errno == 1:
      print 'Process exists, but we cannot kill it'
   else:
      raise
```

This is not required if you know you are always going to have permission to kill the process you are checking for, say because you are running as root or the process is known to be running under the same UID as the process checking it.